# android interactive google street view api

Tags: android, google-street-view

is there an interactive google street view api?

I want to give users an interactive street view experience (whether with google or not), based on passing coordinates to get what the image is

I have seen the static streetview api, thanks for insight

Comment: What do you mean by 'interactive'?

Comment: @MrZander the opposite of the non-interactive static street view images, a distinction google made with their own API

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for Street View Service? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview